# How to fix scala sbt akka-stream and scala-parser-combinators conflict

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, scala-3

For some reason sbt won't load when scala-parser-combinators and akka-stream dependencies are listed as libraryDependencies. When deleting one of these two, reloading sbt works just fine, so there has to be some sort of conflict between those dependencies.

This is the error message:
`Extracting structure failed, reason: not ok build status: Error (BuildMessages(Vector(),Vector(BuildFailure(sbt task failed, see log for details)),Vector(),Vector(),Error)) sbt task failed, see log for details`

Am I missing something? Is there a easy way to fix this?

this is my sbt file:

```
name := "chatbot"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "3.0.2"
val akkaVersion = "2.6.17"

idePackagePrefix := Some("de.htwg.rs.chatbot")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.10",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.10" % "test",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % akkaVersion,
)
```

Comment: akka 2.6.17 was published for scala 3 nightlies - not for the scala 3.0.2 release - https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/30243#issuecomment-955710653 - read the follow on comments for the akka snapshots that have been published for official scala releases

Comment: these newer akka snapshots need scala 3.1.1-RC1